# How to remove/stripp off unique text from a Map of Strings Java

Tags: java, regex

I've got a `Map<String,list<String>>` data structure in which the Key has the following string text:

```
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[69]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[70]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[71]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[72]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[73]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[74]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[75]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[76]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
```

The index numbers represent the current occurrence of that particular element node. However I would like to remove the indexes for the elements for which there is only 1 occurance.

Example:

**From:**

```
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[69]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[70]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
```

**To:**

```
/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/FederalTotals[69]/PeriodBeginDate
/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/FederalTotals[70]/PeriodBeginDate
```

How can I do this in Java

Edit:

@Andreas brings up a good point. My current implementation for getting an indexed XPath is here:

```
public String getFullXPath(Node n) {
    if (null == n)
        return null;

    Node parent;
    Stack<Node> hierarchy = new Stack<Node>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    hierarchy.push(n);

    switch (n.getNodeType()) {
        case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
            parent = ((Attr) n).getOwnerElement();
            break;
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            parent = n.getParentNode();
            break;
        case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE:
            parent = n.getParentNode();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected Node type" + n.getNodeType());
    }

    while (null != parent
            && parent.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE
            && !parent.getNodeName().equals("section")) {
        hierarchy.push(parent);
        parent = parent.getParentNode();
    }

    Object obj;
    while (!hierarchy.isEmpty() && null != (obj = hierarchy.pop())) {
        Node node = (Node) obj;

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { 
            builder.append("/").append(node.getNodeName());

            int prev_siblings = 1;
            Node prev_sibling = node.getPreviousSibling();

            while (null != prev_sibling) {
                if (prev_sibling.getNodeType() == node.getNodeType()) {
                    if (prev_sibling.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName())) {
                        prev_siblings++;
                    }
                }
                prev_sibling = prev_sibling.getPreviousSibling();
            }
            builder.append("[").append(prev_siblings).append("]");
        } 

        else if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
            builder.append("/@");
            builder.append(node.getNodeName());
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Edit:

Added if() {} else conditional as per @Andreas solution but I am not getting my output with indexes as all [1]'s?

```
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { 
            builder.append("/").append(node.getNodeName());

            int prev_siblings = 1;
            Node prev_sibling = node.getPreviousSibling();

            while (null != prev_sibling) {
                if (prev_sibling.getNodeType() == node.getNodeType()) {
                    if (prev_sibling.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName())) {
                        prev_siblings++;
                    }
                }
                prev_sibling = prev_sibling.getPreviousSibling();
            }
            // edit Outside the while loop
            if(prev_siblings == 1 && node.getNextSibling() == null) {
                continue;
            } else builder.append("[").append(prev_siblings).append("]");
        }
```

Now my output is:

```
/PayrollFormInfo/PaidPreparerInfo[1]/Address1[1]
/PayrollFormInfo/PaidPreparerInfo[1]/City[1]
/PayrollFormInfo/PaidPreparerInfo[1]/State[1]
/PayrollFormInfo/PaidPreparerInfo[1]/Zip[1]
```

Looks like your method works but only for the root element.

Comment: Does it have to have to be regex? Why not `string = string.replace("[1]", "");`

Comment: Not necessarily, but I've been trying stuff with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the addition of `getFullXPath` to the question, the solution is fairly simple.

The method is counting the number of "previous siblings" (+1) to know the number to assign. If that number is 1, check if it has a "next sibling", and don't add the number if it doesn't.

Comment: I added what you said and I am not my output as all [1]. THis is the code I added:                 if(prev_siblings == 1) {
                 break;
                } else builder.append("[").append(prev_siblings).append("]");

Comment: If that number is 1, **check if it has a "next sibling"**

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong text. I did do that and it returns me a null pointer exception. if(prev_siblings == 1 && prev_sibling.getNextSibling() == null) {
                     break;
                    } else builder.append("[").append(prev_siblings).append("]");

Comment: At that point `prev_sibling` **is** `null`. You need to use `node`.

Comment: omg, now im out of memory!! FAILED: test
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. FML!!

Comment: Time to *debug* your code, but you don't want that `break`, you just wanted to bypass the append of "[number]".

Comment: Should the conditional                 if(prev_siblings == 1 && node.getNextSibling() == null) {
                 continue;
                } else builder.append("[").append(prev_siblings).append("]"); be outside the while loop?

Comment: Getting a bit lost in the code snippet here, but I believe your original code didn't have any `break` or `continue`, and since you're *only* trying to prevent the append of "[number]", any solution should just be an `if` statement around the code that does that. --- For the rest, debug the code.

Comment: Yes that is working now by putting it outside the while but I notice it only works with the root element. I have edited my question to reflect this. I'd like this to work with all the elements. Do you know of a way to make this work with the other elements?

Comment: The `getNextSibling` test is too simple. You want to know if the next `Element` (if any) has the same *name*. --- Your code might clean up if you create two (private static) helper methods: `countPrevElementsWithName()` and `hasNextElementWithName()`. --- Method names help document the code too.

Comment: Still no avail...I created a new thread based on your comments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320867/indexing-xpath-for-xml-document

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to remove the '[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)' from the string before placing it in the Map.
Something like this

```
Map<String,list<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String,list<String>>();
//lets say variable 'k' has the key and another list v which has value
String k = "/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[69]/PeriodBeginDate[1]";
myMap.put(k.replace("[1]",""), v);
```

Further details on replace function: [String replace() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 1):

First, you'd have to identify that you only have 1 occurrence. Example:

```
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[70]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[71]/PeriodBeginDate[1]
/PayrollFormInfo[1]/CompanyInfo[1]/FederalTotals[71]/PeriodBeginDate[2]
```

Here, PeriodBeginDate for FederalTotals 70 is singular, but PeriodBeginDate for FederalTotals 71 is not.

You current *storage* mechanism makes it extremely difficult to know which can be "shortened".

You need to build a hierarchy structure for your keys, so you can check the "child count" of any node in the hierarchy.

Rather than adding the number when building your first map, build up your data using the new hierarchy structure, and construct the "path" when needed.

Comment: I'm using a Stack to push and pop nodes and counting the previous_sibling and incrementing to get the index number. I use this to append the index number for that particular xpath. I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Using regex and replaceAll:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[1\\]", "");
```

---

Userful links:

[Regex Java Tester Online](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

[JavaSE String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)