# Index path for XML document

Tags: java, xpath, conceptual

I've got an algorithm for indexing an Xpath so that I can process multiple files with the same Xpath but different values via assigning an xpath node a unique index.

**Example:**

File 1:

```
<Return>
  <ReturnData>
    <Person>
      <Name>Yohanna</Name>
    </Person>
  </ReturnData>
</Return>
```

File 2:

```
<Return>
  <ReturnData>
    <Person>
      <Name>Jacoub</Name>
    </Person>
  </ReturnData>
</Return>
```

**Desired output:**

```
1. /Return/ReturnData/Person[1]/Name=Yohanna
2. /Return/ReturnData/Person[2]/Name=Jacoub
```

**My current implementation gives me an output of:**

```
1. /Return/ReturnData[1]/Person[1]/Name[1]=Yohanna
2. /Return/ReturnData[1]/Person[2]/Name[1]=Jacoub
```

I'd like to remove the [1]'s since they are not needed to signify there is only 1 occurrence of this node.

Indexing code:

```
public String getFullXPath(Node n) {
    if (null == n) return null;

    Node parent;
    Stack<Node> hierarchy = new Stack<Node>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    hierarchy.push(n);

    switch (n.getNodeType()) {
        case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
            parent = ((Attr) n).getOwnerElement();
            break;
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            parent = n.getParentNode();
            break;
        case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE:
            parent = n.getParentNode();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected Node type" + n.getNodeType());
    }

    while (null != parent
            && parent.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE
            && !parent.getNodeName().equals("section")) {

        hierarchy.push(parent);
        parent = parent.getParentNode();
    }

    Object obj;
    while (!hierarchy.isEmpty() && null != (obj = hierarchy.pop())) {
        Node node = (Node) obj;

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { 
            builder.append("/").append(node.getNodeName());

            int prev_siblings = 1;
            Node prev_sibling = node.getPreviousSibling();
            while (null != prev_sibling) {
                if (prev_sibling.getNodeType() == node.getNodeType()) {
                    if (prev_sibling.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName())) {
                        prev_siblings++;
                    }
                }
                prev_sibling = prev_sibling.getPreviousSibling();
            }
            // Here is where I say don't append the number of prev_siblings if it equals 1 or the next sibling does not exist
            if(prev_siblings == 1 && node.getNextSibling() == null) {
            } 
            else 
                builder.append("[").append(prev_siblings).append("]");
        } 

        else if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
            builder.append("/@");
            builder.append(node.getNodeName());
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

I've tried fixing this but I am still unable after 3 days of looking into this and debugging...No idea...I know I'm missing something, something I'm not seeing. Any help or assistance would be much appreciated.

Edit:

Added 2 helper methods:

```
private static boolean hasNextElementsWithName(Node node) {
    while (null != node) {
        // checks if next sibling exists
        if(node.getNextSibling().hasAttributes()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


private static int countPrevElementsWithName(Node node, int prev_siblings,
        Node prev_sibling) {
    while (null != prev_sibling) {

        if (prev_sibling.getNodeType() == node.getNodeType()) {
            if (prev_sibling.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName())) { 
                prev_siblings++;
            }
        }
        prev_sibling = prev_sibling.getPreviousSibling();

    }
    return prev_siblings;
}
```

Calling Method:

```
    Object obj;
    while (!hierarchy.isEmpty() && null != (obj = hierarchy.pop())) {
        Node node = (Node) obj;

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { 
            builder.append("/").append(node.getNodeName());

            int prev_siblings = 1;
            Node prev_sibling = node.getPreviousSibling();

            prev_siblings = countPrevElementsWithName(node, prev_siblings,
                    prev_sibling);


             //@Andreas
            int count = countPrevElementsWithName(node, prev_siblings, prev_sibling);
            if(count != 0 || hasNextElementsWithName(node)) {
                builder.append("[").append(count+1).append("]");
            }

        } 

        else if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
            builder.append("/@");
            builder.append(node.getNodeName());
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to use them now?

Comment: Link to original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256218/how-to-remove-stripp-off-unique-text-from-a-map-of-strings-java

Comment: I will repeat my comment: The `getNextSibling` test is too simple. You want to know if the next `Element` (if any) has the same name. --- Your code might clean up if you create two (private static) helper methods: `countPrevElementsWithName()` and `hasNextElementWithName()`. --- Method names help document the code too.

Comment: Added 2 private static methods but I am unsure how to use these methods with what you suggested. Checking if the next element has the same name as the current element node.nextSibling.getNodeName == node.getNodeName results in a nullpointerexception thrown at me

Comment: `int count = countPrevElementsWithSameName(node); if (count != 0 || hasNextElementWithSameName(node)) { builder.append("[").append(count + 1).append("]"); }`

Comment: I did exactly what you just put and my output off: [/Return[2]/ReturnData[2]/Person[2]/Name[2] = Yohanna, /Return[2]/ReturnData[2]/Person[4]/Name[2] = Jacoub]. I think the problem is with the helper methods. How would the helper methods look? I've added the helper methods under edit in my question.

Comment: Well, `hasNextElementsWithName` doesn't do any name comparisons. Return value of `countPrevElementsWithName` is `int`, not `Integer`, and value is `0`, not `1`, if `node` is first.

Comment: So hasNextElementsWithName method just checks if node.getNextSibling != null && node.getNextSibling.getNodeName != null ? I'm a little confused what these methods do especially "WithName" part?

Comment: `<p>  <a/>  <a/>  <b/>  </p>`. First `a` has prevCount = 0 and hasNext = true, second `a` has prevCount = 1 and hasNext = false, and `b` has prevCount = 0 and hasNext = false. This is true even though all the elements are separated by text nodes of a single space, i.e. none of them has an element as either "nextSibling" or "previousSibling". With this, they will be named `/p/a[1]`, `/p/a[2]`, and `/p/b`.

Comment: Good explaination. I see exactly what you are saying but the org.w3c.dom.Node library only provides the nextSibling or previousSibling methods...I'm not sure what method they provide for me to just check if it has a next element?

Comment: You're already doing it elsewhere. You keep calling next/prev and check the type, ignoring anything other than type `Element`.

Comment: Right but in the helper method I mean, you are saying to extarct that from the caller method and have it exclusive in the helper?

Comment: But I am calling nextSibling/prevSibling when I check if it's an element node. You mentioned in the helper method, node object will not have next sibling or prevSibling, just hasNext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Code stub*

```
int count = countPrevElementsWithSameName(node);
if (count != 0 || hasNextElementWithSameName(node))
    builder.append("[").append(count + 1).append("]");
```

*Helper methods*

```
private static final boolean hasNextElementWithSameName(Node node) {
    String name = node.getNodeName();
    for (Node next = node.getNextSibling(); next != null; next = next.getNextSibling())
        if (next.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) // only look at elements
            return next.getNodeName().equals(name); // stop on first element after "node"
    return false;
}
private static final int countPrevElementsWithSameName(Node node) {
    String name = node.getNodeName();
    int count = 0;
    for (Node prev = node.getPreviousSibling(); prev != null; prev = prev.getPreviousSibling())
        if (prev.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { // only look at elements
            if (! prev.getNodeName().equals(name))
                break; // stop when element name changes
            count++; // count elements of same name as "node"
        }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Ohhh my goodness, I was doing doing them completely wrong! Thank you! For all your explainations and help! You've been answering my questions for days! I would like to show you appreciation for your guideance, can you send me paypal address?

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in Java/DOM is just painful, so here is an XSLT solution:

```
<xsl:template match="/" mode="path">
  <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".." mode="path"/>
  <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
  <xsl:number/>
  <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[count(../*)=1]" mode="path">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".." mode="path"/>
  <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//Name">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="path"/>
    <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```

Comment: Good method but this is specific to a particular xml. I must do it in Java since it must work for any XML I feed it

Comment: The only thing specific to the XML source in that stylesheet is the Name element, and of course you can parameterise that, e.g by passing the starting node as a stylesheet parameter.